# DevOps for CouchDB/Cloudant design documents

Tags: couchdb, devops, cloudant, continuous-delivery, delivery-pipeline

Is there any tool/library to integrate with devops tool to manage deployment of Couchdb/Cloudant design documents? Since Couchdb/Cloudant provide HTTP APIs to perform CRUD operations for these design documents, its not a big deal to design/build such a tool/library from scratch, but still it would be better to build on shoulder of tallest to take it further ahead.

Comment: Tool requests are off-topic here, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The “couchapp” concept provides means for design doc management, typically creating them automatically from a directory structure containing map and reduce functions as separate files, and means for deployment. Whilst couchapps themselves have largely been superseded by other technologies, the tooling is often useful in the cases you mention.

Many implementations exist - a quick search for “couchapp” should give you some options.